Special case of expected value convergence
Problem:
I have a special case of convergence of random variables and I would like to show that their expected values also converge.
I have a sequence of random variables $\{X_t\}$, $X_t \stackrel{a.s.}{\longrightarrow} X$, where $\mathbb{E}X = 0, \text{Var}X < \infty$.
Then I have the following random variables $Y_t = f(g_t(X_t))$, where $g_t \stackrel{\text{unif.}}{\longrightarrow} g$. Both $g \colon \mathbb{R} \to [0, 1]$ and $f \colon \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}_{\ge 0}$ are continuous functions. I also know that $g(X) \sim \text{Uniform}(0, 1)$ and that $\mathbb{E}f(g(X)) < \infty$.
I want to prove that $\mathbb{E}Y_t \to \mathbb{E}Y = \mathbb{E}f(g(X))$.
My thoughts:
I know that to prove convergence of expected values there are several ways:

Monotone convergence theorem (inapplicable, since $Y_t$ are not monotonic sequence).
Prove uniform integrability of $Y_t$ (inapplicable, since IDK how to work with $f(g(X_t))$ under the integral).
Dominated convergence theorem (DCT) (may be useful).

To apply DCT I need to show that $|Y_t|=$ [since $f \colon \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}_{\ge 0}$] $= Y_t \le Z$ for all $t$, where $\mathbb{E}Z < \infty$.
I thought that $Z = Y + 1 = f(g(X)) + 1$ could be this bound, because starting from some $T$, for $t > T$ I will have that $Y_t \in (Y - \varepsilon, Y + \varepsilon)$ with probability 1. That means, that $Y_t \le Y+1 = Z$ almost surely. It remains to show that $Z = Y+1$ is integrable. Here is my idea on how to prove it:
$$\int_\mathbb{R} \left( f(x) + 1 \right) d\mathbb{P}_{g(X)} = \int_\mathbb{R} f(x)d\mathbb{P}_{g(X)} + \int_\mathbb{R}1 d\mathbb{P}_{g(X)}$$
First integral is finite because of $\mathbb{E}f(g(X)) < \infty$, second integral is finite, because $\mathbb{P}_{g(X)} = \mathbb{P}_U$ is concentrated on [0, 1], where $\mathbb{P}_U$ is the measure induced by uniform distribution.
Will this proof work?
